# Cannot connect to a pluggable database via IDE

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-xe, datagrip

I have an Oracle XE database on computer1.

When I try to connect to it via sqlplus from computer2, it works fine, for both cdb and pdb connections;
e.g.:

```
rlwrap sqlplus timon@//192.168.0.115:9121/xepdb1                                                                                  

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jun 21 09:40:00 2022
Version 21.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
Last Successful login time: Tue Jun 21 2022 09:39:11 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL>
```

When I try to connect to it via DataGrip IDE:

- I can connect to container database with username "sys as sysdba"
- I cannot connect to pluggable database xepdb1. Settings are following:
  [image: datagrip settings]

Error is following:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to a pluggable database, you need to specify the  `SERVICE_NAME` for it (`forslash notation '/XEPDB1'`), so you will have to specify database type "Oracle Database" and not "Oracle SID" (`colon notation ':XEPDB1'`) in the DataGrip IDE.

Best of luck!

Comment: service name works fine. Thank you for help.